# Lagrange: when a potential force, when a generalized force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

Consider the following case of a drum unrolling a mass that is on a massless string wrapped around the drum:

[image]

According to my professor, here we must consider the mass $m$ being in a gravitational field as a generalized torque that is acting on the drum, i.e. that we have on the right hand side of Lagrange's equations:

$$
Q^*=mgr
$$

Now, consider the case of a pendulum swinging:

[image]

In this case we must consider the change in elevation of the mass $m$ as a change in potential energy! We write for example:

$$
U=mgL(1-\cos(\varphi))
$$

**Big question**: how come in the first example the change in elevation is considered to be a generalized torque while in the second example it is taken as a change in potential energy?? And how can this be generalized such that I make the correct decision when dealing with this for more complicated systems?

Comment: Maybe because he is looking at the cylinder alone and not the system of the cylinder and the mass? I think this makes the mass external and hence the generalised torque. I am sure that the first problem can also be done considering the system as a whole with appropriate constraints and there the potential energy of the mass would have to be used.

Comment: No it is not that. We consider the full system each time. But sometimes we take gravity as torque instead of potential energy. I don't know why, it's the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem, both problems are a force multiplied by a distance. The difference between the two is angle. In torque the distance acts like a lever, a force is amplified by a longer lever. In work done and potential energy (both force multiplied by distance) assumes that distance is in the direction of the force, not at right angles to it.